# animated .GIF and Java

Tags: java, applet, animated-gif

What's the code for displaying an animated .gif inside an applet?

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `ImageIcon` and put it into a `JLabel`, e.g.

```
public class AnimatedGIF {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        final URL location = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/f/f0/20060824220301!Zipper_animated.gif");

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(location)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```